# Unable to access Web Service from Dotnetnuke 7.4

Tags: json, web-services, soap, dotnetnuke

I have a webservice from 3rd party provider, when i try adding webservice and using it in my plain .net application, it worked fine, however now when i am trying to execute it on production environment which have dotnetnuke 7.4.1 installed, it just throws below error.

```
Reference.svcmap: Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'DotNetNuke.Services.Localization.LocalizationExpressionBuilderEditor'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.
```

I am totally lost about this error, even could not find much for this on google.

Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The issue here appears related to CodeAccessSecurity.  If you are using a WSP based module, you might try switching to WAP.

Comment: Yes i am using WSP based module, can you provide some guidance about converting to WAP?

Comment: To be perfectly honest I don't remember.  I haven't used WSP since early 2000's.  You can start with the Christoc template for DNN and work from there.

Comment: Is that your web services are Rest Services?

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to get it working by these steps, I am not sure how useful that be to others though.

Right Click on Service -> Configure Service Reference -> UnCheck 'Reuse Types in referenced assemblies

Thats all it took to get rid of this annoying error message.